Unpack non ascii string in jpos
A parser has been written for ISO 8583 messages based on JPOS version 3  on java 8, along with a corresponding configuration file like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager SYSTEM "genericpackager.dtd">
  <!-- ISO 8583:1987 (ASCII) field descriptions for GenericPackager -->

   <isopackager>
 <isofield
      id="0"
      length="4"
      name="MESSAGE TYPE INDICATOR"
      class="org.com.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
    <isofield
      id="1"
      length="16"
      name="BIT MAP"
      class="org.com.iso.IFA_BITMAP"/>
    <isofield
      id="2"
      length="19"
      name="PAN - PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER"
      class="org.com.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
    <isofield
      id="3"
      length="6"
      name="PROCESSING CODE"
      class="org.com.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  

. How can we use it to parse messages containing non-ASCII characters in some fields, for example, field 48, like that:
0100A238010188C10004000000000400000589000001290644175952751014170129150066037990660379990338532597217990001111111110      069728E110009000O030213ùþ¢ûÿ ¤ îÿö õ000100000008
I tried to Convert Config row 48  from
          class="org.com.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>

to this config
         class="org.com.iso.IFA_TTTLLLCHAR"/>

but doesnt work,from char to char+binary, but didnt work.
any body help?

It's not a good idea to pass a string with encoded characters to parse.
You should get the binary representation, and pass the byte array. In no part of the flow you should have your message represented that way. How did you get that message?
